# Error in obtaining data according to your role ionic and laravel

Tags: angular, laravel, ionic-framework

I am trying to get some data from laravel, classifying it by roles, in short get all users of a role. At the moment of doing it in ionic it only shows me the data of the role, like name and status. I really don't know if I'm doing wrong the query in laravel or getting wrong the service in ionic.

Database

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

The method that makes the query to the database

```
public function searchRol($id){
        try {
            return response()->json(
                ['data' => profile::with('Usuario')->where('rol_id','=', $id)->get()], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(
            [
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
                'msg' => 'Error al mostrar los perfiles'
            ], 500);
        }
        
    }
```

RolService - IONIC

```
export class RolService {
    public url: String = environment.url;
    public rols$ = new Subject<Rol[]>();
    public rol$ = new Subject<Rol>();

    public rols: Rol[] = [];
    public rol: Rol;
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
    all$(): Observable<Rol[]> { // observable sirve para que se pueda subscribir en el componente y recibir la data
        return this.rols$.asObservable();
    }
    all(): Observable<any> { // observable sirve para que se pueda subscribir en el componente y recibir la data
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}rol`).pipe( // <-- URL y pipe es para el error 404
            map((res: any) => {
                this.rols = res.data;
                this.rols$.next(this.rols);
                return res.data;
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                console.log(err);
                return err;
            }),
        );
    }  
    // buscar rol por id del rol
    search(id): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}rol/search/${id}`).pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
                this.rols = res.data;
                this.rols$.next(this.rols);
                return res.data;
            }),
        
        );
    }

}
```

Models

```
class profile extends Model
{
    //Primero se crea un modelo para obetner los datos que estan relacionados con la tabla profile con usaurio y rol
    public function Usuario() {
        return $this->belongsTo(user::class, 'user_id');
    }
    public function Rol() {
        return $this->belongsTo(rol::class, 'rol_id');
    }
}
```

What it shows me when I press a role
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

What I want is that when I press the role, it shows me all the users of that role.

Comment: can you show the relationships you have setup between your models?

Comment: is the relationship setup from User to Profile or from Role to User?

Comment: From user to profile and from profile to role

Comment: You could look into the `whereHas` method: [Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) and then be able to do this from the User side of the relationship so you get a collection of Users